# How do I write data to firestore when creating a new user?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a data entry on the firebase database to store additional information about a user when they register on my site.

I've tried to write data to the database in the .then() function following createUserWithEmailAndPassword() as that's the only way for me to extract the user id for the user (I'm hoping to use the uid as the key field of the record I create)

```
(req, res) => {

        // extract user data from the form
        const newUser = {
            fname: req.body.fname,
            lname: req.body.lname,
            email: req.body.email,
            pw: req.body.pw,
            pw_c: req.body.pw_c
        }

        // carry out validation
        const { valid, errors } = validateRegistrationData(newUser);
        if (!valid) return res.status(400).json(errors);

        // create new firebase user
        firebase
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.pw)
            .then(data => {

                let uid = data.user.uid;

                // make a database entry to store the users info
                // by default, assumes that the user is a secondary user
                let userData = {
                    fname: newUser.fname,
                    lname: newUser.lname,
                    email: newUser.email,
                    utype: 1,
                    createdon: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                    intitems: []
                }

                newUserDoc = db
                                .collection("users")
                                .doc(uid)
                                .set(userData)

                return res.status(200).json("Success: new user created.");
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if (err.code === "auth/email-already-in-use"){
                    return res.status(400).json({ email: "Email is already in use" });
                } else {
                    return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
                }
            });

        return res.status(200).json("Success: new user created.");
    }
```

The server responds with `{Success: new user created."}`. The authentication part seems to work as a new user is created in the `Authentication` section of my firebase console. However, no new data entries appear in the `users` collection of my database.

Comment: Take the return `then` or `catch` on your `set` method.

Comment: `return res.status(200).json("Success: new user created.");` is executed before the asynchronous `set()` operation is completed, this is why the record is not created.

Comment: Look the Dan's answer. If you have error, please update your question with the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.set` returns a promise that still needs to run to completion. However, currently you're not waiting on the promise, and instead just responding via `res.send`.

You can append .then(() => { do stuff here }) to the end of `.set`. If it's the last thing you're doing in that function, you can just do res.send from there.

```
return db.collection("users").doc(uid).set(userData).then(() => {
          return res.status(200).json("Success: new user created.");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error) 
        })
```